# UWP sideload app that use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook COM

Tags: outlook, uwp, com, office-interop, com-interop

Hello Im updating a UWP app that we use in ouroffice.

Before when we use it to send email it uses the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage` however this i really limited. So i would like to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` instead to create the email directly with outlook

My test code looks like this.

```
try
        {
            List<string> lstAllRecipients = new List<string>();
            //Below is hardcoded - can be replaced with db data
            lstAllRecipients.Add("info@test.com");
            //lstAllRecipients.Add("chandan.kumarpanda@testmail.com");

            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector;
            // Thread.Sleep(10000);

            // Recipient
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMailItem.Recipients;
            foreach (String recipient in lstAllRecipients)
            {
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
                oRecip.Resolve();
            }

            ////Add CC
            //Outlook.Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add("THIYAGARAJAN.DURAIRAJAN@testmail.com");
            //oCCRecip.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
            //oCCRecip.Resolve();

            //Add Subject
            oMailItem.Subject = "Test Mail";

            // body, bcc etc...

            //Display the mailbox
            oMailItem.Display(true);
        }
        catch (Exception objEx)
        {
            await new MessageDialog(objEx.Message, "Error email to Outlook").ShowAsync();
        }
```

I have added the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll version to the app by finding it in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll it is file version 15.0.4569.1507

My problem is when i run the code i get the following error

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Please make sure your COM object is in the allowed list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp.

I guees i have to add a reference in the appxmanifest how ever i cannot figure out what.

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/06/calling-winrt-components-win32-process-via-desktop-bridge/

Comment: Thanks how would that then look for Outlook? <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" ThreadingModel="both" />
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>

Comment: A supported way to do this is via a full-trust process that you can launch from your UWP -- it will be able to manipulate the Office apps. Look at "Desktop Bridge" samples.

Comment: Hello @Peter Following the Desktop Bridge samples i changed the appxmanifest for add the `<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>` However when i change the EntryPoint to EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" the app wont start and i get the following error: Unable to activate Windows Store app The application apperars to be already running. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you include a regular Win32 app as the entry point? Check out the samples (try modifying one of them) to get started - [Desktop Bridge Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT That was what I was missing thank you.

Comment: Hi Kasper S Mathiesen, I am also stuck at implementing the Outlook with my UWP application  . Basically i waned to send email with attachement and happened to see this discussion . Would it be possible for you share a  code sample  ? Hope its already working for you ?